# I require regex for entering numerical decimal values and colon for android

Tags: android

I need to enter only **decimal numeric values with two decimal points** or **9:9999**.

```
e.g. 665.44, 95.09 etc 
else only 9:999
```

If some body has a good link how to understand **regex** and create logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

> ^\d+(.\d+){0,1}$

Expression means:

- $ -> The end of the string
- \d -> the digit
- ^ -> start of string

`(.\d+){0,1}` -> you can insert 1 or more than 1 digit in string, but you can insert only 1 times dot(.) in string, not more than 1 dot (.) in string.

```
 ^\d+\.\d{0,2}$ //where "2" is the maximum allowed decimal places.
```

[For more details](http://regexlib.com/%28A%28_qbFczk55FhfDusmogRfgpw3EDgiBWSLXod9jt0BKoF1sqKCfe5sn8gnpYBE7xcc00n4umtMt37BunFVCHQfhCWUtEWCR59CmV5ZJ92Pjso1%29%29/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). One way to use it:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
Log.i("Formatted Number:",df.format(decimalNumber)+"");
```

Another one is to construct it using the #.## format.

```
double d = 1.234567;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
Log.i("Formatted Number",df.format(d)+"");
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask to show formatted number, but to validate an input.